# In C# is there a way to reference remote .csproj file?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm a newcomer to c# and I know the question is a little confusing but here's my problem, I have two projects accessing the same azure database and one of those projects must access the .csproj file of the other.

Here's my code:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors" Version="2.2.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All"/>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Project2\Project2.csproj" Version="2.2.0"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

This code works as intended if I run the project locally.
The problem is that when I try to deploy to azure, this project fails to build because it can't find the location of the remote Project2.csproj file.

The projects are located in different repositories and therefore can't see eachother.

Is there a way to reference remote projects? Using the repository url perhaps? Thanks!

Comment: May you need to create a "common class library", that can be used by more than one project at a time.

Comment: If the projects are in different repos, you should look to have a Nuget package to host the common library. Alternatively, you can look at using Git submodules, but I rarely see that working very well.

Comment: *"one of those projects must access the .csproj file of the other"* - That's not a problem you're trying to solve, that's how you think you need to solve it.  What's the underlying problem?  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you want to build online, you have to provide the source code, or it doesn't work. Azure will not collect the sources from different spots. If you don't want to upload the sources, you have to upload the binary - than you link to an assemby that you built locally on your computer and you use this Assembly as a PackageReference, not as ProjectReference. (Which is about the same as the other commenters said, just in other words).

Comment: @David basically Project1 uses a few of Project2's files and the way I was able to solve it locally was to reference Project2's .csproj file. The problem is that, because the projects don't share a repo, that file is not visible when I try to deploy to azure

Comment: I'll give a shot to the common library and binary. Never used them so it might take a while. Thanks!

Comment: @H.Soares: *"Project1 uses a few of Project2's files"* - For what purpose?  What kind of files?  Why are they used?  It really sounds like you took a wrong turn in your design some time ago.  Whatever it is you're trying to do, there's likely a better way to do it.

Comment: @David This is a school project and basically Project1 manages products and Project2 manages orders and each order can have several products. I know it would be simpler to have everything in just one project but I don't think that's the intended goal.

Comment: You can have multiple projects in a single solution (and single repo), that is most likely what you should be doing here.

Comment: i have not understand yet your problem , it's seems that you need to référence Project A in Project B, but still not clear for me you are talking about a dll or csproj file ?

Comment: i think if you use th binairies of the project 2  in project 1 at the place of project reference , it's should work

Comment: @sayahimad I'm talking about a csproj file

Comment: "when I try to deploy to azure"? You are not supposed to deploy source code. Check `dotnet publish` please.